# I am trying to copy and rename a sheet but I get subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy Sheet2 to Sheet3 and rename it to Result but I keep getting subscript out of range error (which happens because that sheet doesn't exist which probably means that the copying isn't happening).

I tried using Copy as shown in the code below but the subscript out of range error keeps coming up. Any help resolving this is really appreciated. Thanks!

```
    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'trying to copy Sheet2 and create a Sheet3 tab
    shtSheet2.Copy After:=Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set shtSheet3 = Sheets(Sheets("Sheet3").Index + 1)
    shtSheet3.Name = "Result"
```

Comment: I tried this code in excel 2010 and it is working fine. May be you must have tried in excel 2013 and above, where the default number of sheets in a new workbook is 1. So you might be getting the `subscript out of range` exception when trying to copy the sheet which does not exist.

Comment: @Arul I believe that is right. Do you know how I can fix this in Excel 13?

Comment: @VBasic2008 not sure what you mean. I only have Sheet1 and Sheet2 in my excel book. The idea is when I run the module Sheet3 (renamed to Result) should autogenerate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Copy Sheet

### After Sheet2

```
Sub NewSheetAfterSheet2()

  Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
  Dim shtSheet3 As Worksheet
  Set shtSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
```

> ```
>   shtSheet2.Copy After:=shtSheet2
>   Set shtSheet3 = Sheets(shtSheet2.Index + 1)
>   shtSheet3.Name = "Result"
> ```

```
End Sub
```

### Last Position

```
Sub NewSheetLastPosition()

  Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
  Dim shtSheet3 As Worksheet
  Set shtSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
```

> ```
>   shtSheet2.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
>   Set shtSheet3 = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
>   shtSheet3.Name = "Result"
> ```

```
End Sub
```

Comment: I get object variable or With block variable not set. Do I have to add "Result" somewhere else?

Comment: Which one did you try?